# How to fix this error duplicate class found in module class.jar

Tags: build.gradle

I got this error when I try to generate signed apk for my project

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.5.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1)
>   Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics found
>   in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1)
>   Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1)
>   Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Param
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1)
>   Duplicate class
>   com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty found in
>   modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0) and
>   classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

how do I fix It?

Answer (score 8):

Try with

```
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$project.playServicesVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

You can Try including one by one the one which brings errors you apply

```
 implementation("**API**") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

**NB** `$project.playServicesVersion` could be any of your versions you are using

Comment: thanks for replying, I tried but still the same error

Comment: it could be there is another import that includes 'com.google.android.gms' which needs exclusion. Try to run gradle to see how dependencies are interlinked using ./gradlew app:dependencies

Answer (score 2):

For those who face this type of issue in the future

Ensure that you are using the specific dependency of play services according to your requirements. In my case, I need a map dependency but I am importing the play service dependency which causes duplicate class issues with another firebase dependency.

Use this

```
def playServiceVersion = "17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServiceVersion"
```

Instead of

```
def playServiceVersion = "17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$playServiceVersion"
```

For further information check the link below

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

Reason: This error usually occurs due to depedencies using same functionality.

Solution: To revolve such issue is to comment: play-services because play-services-maps has same functions like play-services and also display locations on our android UI system. Please see below for solution.

//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

Also checkout notable transitive dependencies: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

I hope its help solve so many developers project issues.